# How can I resize my offerwall in my wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I want to integrate an offerwall from Adscend Media on my Wordpress website but I don't know a single thing about coding and I don't really understand what I have to do. They have a guide on how to integrate the offerwall but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It is something like this:

**Integration Instructions**
Integrate the Offer Wall on your website by adding the IFRAME tag shown above wherever you want the Offer Wall displayed. Next, you must insert your user's unique userid in the URL used by the iframe at the end after "subid1=". This allows the Offer Wall to give the user their history of completed offers, remove offers that have already been completed by the user, and allow you to track how much each user has earned and what offers they have completed.
**A typical PHP implementation would look similar to this:**

```
$userID = getUserIDfromDatabase();

echo '<iframe src="https://asmwall.com/adwall/publisher/116068/profile/18966?subid1=' . $userID . ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

When I create a HTML Block on my page (I use Elementor) and paste the IFrame there it works but the width is ok and the height is extremely small.
I can provide more details but like I said I am not a very good dev and yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there @andrei and welcome. If you are having an issue because the height is small, then do this. Take that code you pasted here, and add the following
**width/height** parameters like so:

```
$userID = getUserIDfromDatabase();

echo '<iframe width="500" height ="500" src="https://asmwall.com/adwall/publisher/116068/profile/18966?subid1=' . $userID . ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

and that should get you going. I added a width/height of "500" pixels so that you can see it. It should show up fine but, if still too small, then play with the numbers until you find something that feels/looks good.

Happy coding.